# customize scrollbar design for any div but not for the body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to customize the scrollbar design. But it changer the scrollbar in the body also. I wants it only for selected divs. How can I do it?

Comment: First of all, you would need to show us your code, and what have tried so far?

Comment: try using http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Comment: why code is important here?

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and this http://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how to post a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class before defining the scrollbar style on your CSS.

```
/* Scrollbars */
.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #8B8B8B;
}
.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #C40030;
}
.custom-scroll * {
    scrollbar-face-color: #8b8b8b;
    scrollbar-track-color: #e0e0e0;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #C40030;
}
/* END Scrollbars */
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oLh66xut/1/